# Do we need both tags "event travel" and "events"?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-synonyms, tag-wikis

Well it turns out we have these two apparently very similar tags. I've included their tag wiki excerpts:

- [event-travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/event-travel) **× 19** Travel for the purpose of seeing or experiencing a particular occasion
- [events](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/events) **× 5** Occurrences and happenings, usually set at a specific, limited time period.

Until I just retagged a Marrakesh question no question had used both of them.

I've always been of the opinion that it's redundant to include the word `travel` in our tags. It's like including `programming` in tags on Stack Overflow. So I prefer the latter tag even though it has fewer uses and is probably newer.

I think the best thing to do would be to make the newer one a synonym of the older one first so that the original tag creator doesn't get penalized as far as getting badges when enough questions use the tag. But then I would rename the tag to just `events`. I wouldn't bother keeping the synonym with `-travel` in it, but I'm not sure how tag merging works internally so I don't want anything to break.

Since they both have tag wikis as well as excerpts, some thought should be put in to merging the wording.

Answer (score 3):

I agree they should be merged.

In addition, I think the tag "event-based-effects" should be renamed "incident-based-effects" to make it more distinct.

Comment: Not all events are incidents though. Doesn't incident have a somewhat negative connotation?